# unable to add row to a winforms datagridview that is bound to a SortableBindngList

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that was bound to a generic List<> of my objects.   Everything works fine.   I then changed the List to a SortableBindingList so that I can sort the columns.   This works fine to except now I get an exception when I try to add a row.   The exception is:

"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

This occurs in the WinForms runtime in DatagridView.DataGridviewDataConnection.ProcessListChanged method.

Anyone have any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: I tried to add the code to the SortableBindingList but was unable to.  Is it possible I need to add a method or event to it?

Comment: When working with bound data structures, you should add the new row to the underlying data, not to the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have separated your data from how it is displayed. Good for you! Too often I see that people try to fiddle with cells and rows instead of using the datasource.

However, if your DataSource is a `List<...>`, the changes that the operator makes to the DatagridView are not reflected in the DataSource.

If you want that items that are added / removed / changed by the operator are also changed in your DataSource, you should use an object that implements `IBindingList`, like (surprise!) [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=net-5.0)

You forgot to tell us what you show in your DataGridView, let's assume you show `Products`

```
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public int StockCount {get; set;}
    public string LocationCode {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Using visual studio designer you've added the columns that you want to show. You'll have to tell which column shows which property. For instance in the constructor:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    // define which columns show which properties
    columnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Id);
    columnName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Name);
    columnPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Price);
    ...
```

To make access to the displayed products easy, add a Property:

```
private BindingList<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<Product>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource,
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}
```

Initialization:

```
private void ShowProducts()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> queryProducts = this.FetchProducts();
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(queryProducts.ToList());
}
```

Now whenever the operator adds / removes a row, or edits the cells in a row, the BindingList is automatically updated, even if the columns are rearranged, or the data sorted.

If the operator indicates that he finished editing the data, for instance by pressing a button, you immediately have all updated information:

```
private void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<Product> displayedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts;

    // find out what is added / removed / changed
    this.ProcessEditedProducts(displayedProducts);
}
```

If you need to access selected items, consider to add the following properties:

```
private Product CurrentProduct => (Product)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow?.DataBoundItem;

private IEnumerable<Product> SelectedProducts => this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<Product>();
```

If the operator adds a row, he starts with a row that is constructed using the default constructor. If you don't want this, but for instance initialize the Id, or the LocationCode, consider to subscribe to event [BindingList AddingNew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.addingnew?view=net-5.0)

```
this.DisplayedProducts.AddingNew += OnAddingNewProduct;

void OnAddingNewProduct(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewObject = new Product
    {
        Id = this.GenerateProductId(),
        Name = "Please enter product name>",
        LocationCode = "Unknown Location",
        ...
    };
}
```